Is there any difference between view-source and queryselector
Introduction
When trying to scrape some data on a third party website realized that if I used document.querySelector had different results from what view-source URI scheme.
Description
The query selector I am using is document.querySelector('script[data-target="react-app.embeddedData"]');. There is only one script tag matching that query.
When I execute that query the innerText of the script tag displays no results:

However when I use view-source the results array is not empty:

I already know that the element's content is dynamic. I executed the querySelector before and after checking the view source and viceversa. In all scenarios view source displays the results as expected but not using querySelector.
Software version

Google Chrome Versión 125.0.6422.141 (Build oficial) (64 bits)


Is it possible that the contents of the script tag are changed once the page loads? (which does obviously not happen with "view-source:")

I tried with a normal script tag content in html file and ran it in chrome.
It seems to work.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="application/json" data-target="react-app.embeddedData">
        {"payload" : {"header_redesign_enabled" : true, "results" : [{"a" : 1, "b" : 2}]}}
    </script>
    <script>
        console.log(document.querySelector('script[data-target="react-app.embeddedData"]').innerText);
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Can you provider more detailed data or better example to test with
